Show that $\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}=(\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}})^n$
Let $A$ be a unital commutative ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and let $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ denote the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{m}$. I want to show that
$\mathfrak{m}^{n}A_{\mathfrak{m}}=(\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}})^n$
What is the quickest way to show this? I tried to show it directly but sums of products of sums are hard to keep track of. I know that the ideal $\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$. Would this be useful?

By induction on $n$. For $n=1$ it is clear, instead
$$(\mathfrak{m} A_{\mathfrak{m}})^n=mA_{\mathfrak{m}}(mA_{\mathfrak{m}})^{n-1}=mA_{\mathfrak{m}}\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}A_{\mathfrak{m}}=\mathfrak{m}^{n}A_{\mathfrak{m}}$$
Here I used the commutativity of $A$.
